# Why is ApplyImpulse not working on physicsBody?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, physics, game-physics

I am following a tutorial to fire a ball from a cannon using applyImpulse but it is not working, it is just dropping down to the bottom after I touched the screen?!

```
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let ball:SKSpriteNode = SKScene(fileNamed: "Ball")!.childNodeWithName("ball")! as! SKSpriteNode
    ball.removeFromParent()
    self.addChild(ball)
    ball.zPosition = 0
    ball.position = cannon.position
    let angleInRadians = Float(cannon.zRotation)
    let speed = CGFloat(75.0)
    let vx:CGFloat = CGFloat(cosf(angleInRadians)) * speed
    let vy:CGFloat = CGFloat(sinf(angleInRadians)) * speed
    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(vx, vy))
}
```

Comment: why do you: ball.removeFromParent()?

Comment: If I remove this, there is no ball

Comment: I did it , not sure how, think it just needed a clean?!

Comment: I am guessing the problem was you had a wrong filename "ball" or "Ball" than the actual filename? Just a guess